# Plesk, enable multiple PHP instances of same versions

Tags: php, centos, plesk

I have a **Plesk** installation where I already have a number of domains and they can have their own **PHP** versions.

I have a situation where I want to set up a **test domain**. This needs to use the same **PHP version** as the actual domain but I don't want it to share the same **PHP processes**. In particular, it should not share same set of PHP extensions, which is configured in Plesk on a per version level, not per domain level.

However I don't see a way to do this with **Plesk** or I don't even know if this is possible or not.

I want to ensure that testing will not adversely impact other domains so a bit extra separation is wanted.

Note: normally, one would set up a separate server for testing; however, this is not practical in this particular situation, so if this is wrong approach, I'd like to hear suggestions on how one can support testing on a shared server without being disruptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can create semi-isolated PHP handler by

```
# cp -r /opt/plesk/php/7.1 /opt/plesk/php/7.1_test

# /usr/local/psa/bin/php_handler --add -id 7.1.2-test -displayname 7.1.2-test -path /opt/plesk/php/7.1_test/bin/php-cgi  -clipath /opt/plesk/php/7.1_test/bin/php -phpini /opt/plesk/php/7.1_test/etc/php.ini -type fastcgi

# now add xdebug extension to /opt/plesk/php/7.1_test/etc/php.ini
# echo "extension=/opt/plesk/php/7.1_test/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"  >> /opt/plesk/php/7.1_test/etc/php.ini
```

There is only issue that this PHP handler will still takes loaded extension from original `/opt/plesk/php/7.1/etc/php.d/` because this path is compiled and as I see [it can't be redefined in php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

*ORIGIN ANSWER*

**For Windows** you can set separate IIS Application pool:
[image: Plesk IIS Application Pool]

**For Linux** you can just make use that domain is using PHP-FPM handler:

```
29271 ?        Ss     0:00      0  3408 129231 5800  0.5 php-fpm: master process (/opt/plesk/php/7.0/etc/php-fpm.conf)
29584 ?        S      0:00      0  3408 149283 16624  1.6  \_ php-fpm: pool d1.cl1.a10-52-31-113.qa.plesk.ru
29593 ?        S      0:00      0  3408 149283 16624  1.6  \_ php-fpm: pool cl1.a10-52-31-113.qa.plesk.ru
```

Comment: Just to confirm the understanding. I'm using Linux (CentOS), and the main domain is already using PHP-FPM. If I add 2nd domain, it will show in Plesk that there are 2 domains on PHP 5.4.6 FPM. That gave me the notion that they are somehow shared. You are saying that despite the impression on the Plesk' admin page, it is still their own PHP processes, correct?

Comment: One more issue - it is not possible to enable PHP extension only for one domain but not the other domain even though they use the same PHP version.

Comment: Great, that might be what I need - will test and confirm when I can.